# strcpy a item from dirent to a char[]

Tags: c, pointers, indexing

Doing PSET6, the indexes portion. Got it working but when I tried to move the result from one pointer, from malloc, to a pointer `Char*[]`, the compiler threw a fit.
Here is the relevant piece of code

```
  char *indexedPath = malloc(strlen(path) + strlen("/index.html") + 1);
  DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* sd;
    dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL)
        {
            printf("error\n");
           return 1;
        }
    while(  (sd = readdir(dir))  != NULL   )
        {
            if (strcmp(sd->d_name, "index.html") == 0)
              {
               strcpy(indexedPath, path);
               strcat(indexedPath, "index.html");
               char* type[sizeof(indexedPath)+1];
               strcpy(type, indexedPath);
               free(indexedPath);
               return type;
              }
```

this is the result of the compilation:

```
~/workspace $ make indexes3
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow    indexes3.c  -lcs50 -lm -o indexes3
indexes3.c:36:24: error: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[8]' to parameter of type 'char *'
      [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                strcpy(type, indexedPath);
                       ^~~~
/usr/include/string.h:129:39: note: passing argument to parameter '__dest' here
extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
                                      ^
indexes3.c:38:21: error: incompatible pointer types returning 'char *[8]' from a function with result type
      'char *' [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             return type;
                    ^~~~
indexes3.c:38:21: error: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'type' returned
      [-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address]
             return type;
```

I've been scratching my head over this for days. We have to free the memory in the function since we cannot change main. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a question about this error message, perhaps? "error: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[8]' to parameter of type 'char *'"... The reason I ask is as it stands, there's no question here.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* type[sizeof(indexedPath)+1];
strcpy(type, indexedPath);
free(indexedPath);
return type;
```

This is a very tight mixture of errors, some compilation errors and others subtle runtime errors disguised as "it works!" so when you fix the compilation errors, you're sure to be misled.

---

Lets start with that subtly misleading one, first. The array you have declared, which you later return the pointer of, will be destroyed when the function returns. To reiterate, you're returning a dangling pointer (a pointer that points at nothing).

While this may work for you at the moment (once you fix the compilation errors), it's not guaranteed, portable or in any way reliable. You'll probably notice it stops working in short notice.

One solution is to return `indexedPath` (as opposed to `free`ing it here); that won't be destroyed when the function returns. Unfortunately the caller will have to `free` that chunk of memory.

Better yet, you could change your function to accept an argument that tells you where to store the string (e.g. `fgets` style).

---

That'll likely solve the compilation problem, too, but only because you won't need `indexedPath` or any of the logic based on it, which is what's causing the compilation error. Let's discuss that, next.

Here is what a `char *` variable looks like:

```
char *foo;
```

Here is what your variable looks like:

```
char *foo[bar];
```

Do you see the inconsistency? Your compiler is telling you the first argument for `strcpy` needs to be a `char *`. You could also provide a `char[bar]` array, which would be implicitly converted to a `char *`. Such an array would be declared like so:

```
char foo[bar];
```

However, as we previously discussed, that would be destroyed as your function returns, meaning you'd be returning a dangling pointer. Not a very good solution, eh?